# How to set value of an image custom option programmatically Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, product, cart, custom-options, image

I'm trying to set a image Custom Option in a php script before adding the product to cart. Relevant code looks like this:

```
$specialId = 123;
$customOptions[$specialId] = "Special instruction custom option";

// $imageId = 124;
// $url = 'http://example.com/url/to/image.png';
// $customOptoins[$imageId] = $url;

$params = [
    'product' => $product_id,     //product Id
    'qty'     => $qty,            //quantity of product
    'options' => $customOptions   //custom options
];

$this->_cart->addProduct(
    $_product,
    $params
);
```

I'm starting with an image url as the code implies. I think I have to use `Magento\Framework\Api\Data\ImageContentInterface`, `Magento\Catalog\Model\Webapi\Product\Option\Type\File\Processor` and maybe curl, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: First, try to set image in product and after that you can add that data to the cart and save it.

Comment: do you got any solution on this